# Basic Input-Output System in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I've been trying to do basic input/output stuff in batch. In this bit of code, the user puts in a series of directions in the *:1* section (in notepad) and that sets off a chain reaction that will eventually show one of five images once the file is executed.

```
@echo off

:1
set dun1croomnow=5c
set direction=South
    if %direction%==North set dir=n
    if %direction%==East set dir=e
    if %direction%==South set dir=s
    if %direction%==West set dir=w

set d1a7=n
set d1c5=y
set d1d2=n
set d1d7=n

:d1areset
set dun1c=%dun1croomnow%%d1d2%%d1c5%%d1a7%%d1d7%

:dun1p1c1
if %dun1c%==nonHnnnn goto d1p1cempty

if %dun1c%==5cHnynn goto d1p1c
if %dun1c%==5cHnyyn goto d1p1c
if %dun1c%==5cHnyny goto d1p1c
if %dun1c%==5cHyynn goto d1p1c
if %dun1c%==5cHyyyn goto d1p1c
if %dun1c%==5cHyyny goto d1p1c

if %dun1c%==nonHnynn goto d1p1c2
if %dun1c%==nonHnyyn goto d1p1c2
if %dun1c%==nonHnyny goto d1p1c2
if %dun1c%==nonHyynn goto d1p1c2
if %dun1c%==nonHyyyn goto d1p1c2
if %dun1c%==nonHyyny goto d1p1c2

if %dun1c%==5cHnyyy goto d1p2c
if %dun1c%==nonHnyyy goto d1p2c2
if %dun1c%==5cHyyyy goto d1p2c
if %dun1c%==nonHyyyy goto d1p2c2

:d1p1cempty
    echo                                                    :                  
    echo                                                    :(C)                 
    echo                                                    :  
pause >nul
goto dun1p1d1
:d1p1c
    echo                           \ :                      :                  
    echo                            [%dir%]                     :(C)                 
    echo                           /                        :   
pause >nul
goto dun1p1d1
:d1p1c2
        echo                           \ :                      :                  
        echo                            [ ]                     :(C)                 
        echo                           /                        :   
pause >nul
goto dun1p1d1
:d1p2c
    echo                           \ :         :            :                  
    echo                            [%dir%]        :            :(C)                 
    echo                           /           :            :        
pause >nul
goto dun1p1d1
:d1p2c2
        echo                           \ :         :            :                  
        echo                            [ ]        :            :(C)                 
        echo                           /           :            :        
pause >nul
goto dun1p1d1

:dun1p1d1
pause
```

The information you input into section *:1* should determine the image shown to you in command prompt, but only section *:d1p1cempty*'s image will appear, no matter what you put into *:1*.

Can someone help?

Comment: Put some `echo` statements in to see what you're actually ending up with in `%dunc1%` before all your if statements. Basic debugging in a batch file consists of echoing output at various places to find out where it's going astray. Also, all of your `if %direction%` statements are useless, because immediately above them you `set direction=South` but then test for other values. You'll always (100% of the time) execute the match for `South`.

Comment: Also, you have two large paragraphs that describe (and count) variable names and assignments which are clearly shown in the code above them. That text is unnecessary and redundant, as anyone who might possibly be able to help you will be able to see them in the code itself. Please edit to remove that and more clearly describe the *problem* with the same effort you put into pointlessly describing the code.

Comment: K, thanks for the help. Btw, you're supposed to put the direction inputs into the text file itself. Same with everything else in section :1. So duh.

Comment: This is part of a larger project that includes North, East, South, and West in different sections. North, East, South, and West correlate with n, e, s, and w, but they are different.

Comment: Also, found out what I did wrong. Thanks, Ken. Turns out that I forgot to add an H command in :1. All of the if %dun1c% statements in :dunp1c1 have H commands in them.

Comment: -You can still move that part out and Set "dir=%direction:~,1%" as I already stated.-                                                                                            Ok, I'll try it.

Comment: Yeah, what does this command do exactly? Cause it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @zkm, `Set "dir=%direction:~,1%"` `Set`s `%dir%` to contain the value of the first character of `%direction%`, the only way it doesn't work is if `%direction%` has no characters!